# Change Attribute of another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model

I have the table "tools" and "lend".

Im using Rails3 and when i create a lend i would like it change the attribute status of the tool to 'U'.

Would this is possible?

i tried on the model lend

```
 after_save :change_status

  def change_status
      tools.update_attribute(status, 'U')
  end
```

i tried too, on the same model:

```
 after_save :change_status

  def change_status
      self.tool.update_attribute(status, 'U')
  end
```

No success or warning on debug log.

Sugestions?

Thanks! :)

Comment: the attribute is 'tool' or 'tools'?

Comment: tool is the model/table that storage the tools. The attribute that i wanna change is "status"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the relationship between lend and tool? If Lend has_many tools, you will have to do something like this:

```
def change_status
  tools.each { |tool| tool.update_attributes(status: 'U') }
end
```

Note also that I am using update_attributes because update_attribute (singular) will be deprecated soon.

BTW, you should create a method in Tool to update the attribute, the Lend model should not be aware about how to set a tool as loaned. Something like

```
def loaned!
  update_attributes status: 'U'
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Alain! :) Everything runs ok now! :)

Comment: @drmwndr : please mark my comment as the answer so the question can be closed

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I assume that your Lend model has_many :tools

In order to be able to do something like `tool.update_attribute` you'll need to work with the `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

Take a look at these links and they will probably set you on the right path:
[RailsCasts #196 Nested Model Form Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)
[Active Record Nested Attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Theo! I missed the accepts_nested_attributes. Your tip w/ tip of Alain made the things work ok! :) Thank U! :)